# SQL Server 2014 standard edition slows the machine when Database size grows

Tags: sql-server

I have a scenario where an application server saves 15k rows per second in SQL Server database. At first initial hours machine is still usable but whenever the database size increases ~20gig, it seems that machine is becoming unusable.

I saw some topics/forums/answers/blogs suggesting to limit the max memory usage of SQL Server. Any thoughts on this?

Btw, using SQL Bulkcopy to insert rows in the database.

Comment: Consider taking this to the right place (not a programming question) and providing some more information. I can only assume your "database server" is totally unsuitable to work with larger databases. But you seem to think we can magically solve this without having any background information.

Comment: Even if this was on-topic for SO, we have nowhere near enough information to help with this. There are many reasons why a database may slow down, memory, disk, cache etc.

Comment: sorry about that @TomTom , just got really confused on what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two suggestions for you:

**1 - Database settings:**

When you create the database, try to use a large initial size, and consider to have a bigger autogrowth percentage/size.

You will want to minimize the times your filegroups need to grow.

**2 - Server settings:**

In your SQL Server settings I would recommend that you remove one logical processor from the SQL Server. The OS will use this processor when the SQL Server is busy with heavy loads on the other processors. In my experience, this usually gives a nice boost to the OS .